# Efficiently getting numpy.argmin and numpy.amin at the same time

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Is it possible to get the result of both numpy.argmin and numpy.amin with a single call to numpy? Thanks.

Comment: what's wrong with calling it on separate lines or separated by a comma?

Comment: well. i was thinking if there is a single check of the array that can do both argmin and amin. Checking the array once for argmin and then once more for amin seems to waste time. Or doing this is actually slower?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `np.argmin` to get the indices corresponding to the minimum values and then use those with [`NumPy's advanced indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to get the minimum values.

Let's take a `2D` array to showcase the usage. Let `A` be a `2D` array and let's say we are interested in finding the minimum indices and values along `axis=1`.

Thus, we can do -

```
min_idx = np.argmin(A,axis=1)
min_val = A[np.arange(A.shape[0]),min_idx]
```

Let's take an actual `2D` array for a sample run and verify the results -

```
In [16]: A
Out[16]: 
array([[79, 97, 12, 54, 59],
       [44, 45, 42, 78, 32],
       [32, 41, 67, 60,  4],
       [24,  4, 85, 94, 65]])

In [17]: min_idx = np.argmin(A,axis=1)

In [18]: A[np.arange(A.shape[0]),min_idx] # Using min_idx & indexing
Out[18]: array([12, 32,  4,  4])

In [19]: np.amin(A,axis=1)                # Using np.amin to verify
Out[19]: array([12, 32,  4,  4])
```

---

Runtime test -

```
In [26]: def original_app(A):
    ...:     min_idx = np.argmin(A,axis=1)
    ...:     min_val = np.amin(A,axis=1)
    ...:     return min_idx, min_val
    ...: 
    ...: def proposed_app(A):
    ...:     min_idx = np.argmin(A,axis=1)
    ...:     min_val = A[np.arange(A.shape[0]),min_idx]
    ...:     return min_idx, min_val
    ...: 

In [27]: A = np.random.randint(0,99,(4000,5000))

In [28]: %timeit original_app(A)
10 loops, best of 3: 70.9 ms per loop

In [29]: %timeit proposed_app(A)
10 loops, best of 3: 33.1 ms per loop
```

Let's dissect the timings a bit more -

```
In [31]: min_idx = np.argmin(A,axis=1)

In [32]: %timeit np.argmin(A,axis=1)              # Used in both methods
10 loops, best of 3: 34.5 ms per loop

In [33]: %timeit np.amin(A,axis=1)                # Original approach
10 loops, best of 3: 37.3 ms per loop

In [34]: %timeit A[np.arange(A.shape[0]),min_idx] # Proposed approach
10000 loops, best of 3: 56 µs per loop
```

As we can see a major gain with the advanced indexing at the last step with negligible runtime spent on it. This allows almost 100% runtime-shaving off with it!

Comment: i was thinking about this one too. might do some timing later.

Comment: @rxu Added timings for a `2D` case with a shape of `(4000,5000)`.

Answer (score 2):

### Updated version

A very clean and simple approach is to use `take_along_axis`.

Take:

```
In [1]: A = np.array([[[5, 1, 2, 3]], [[3, 5, 1, 7]]])
```

and apply:

```
In [2]: min_idx = np.argmin(A, axis=2)
In [3]: min_val = np.take_along_axis(A, min_idx[:,:,None], axis=2)[:,:,0]
```

That's it! `min_val` is equal to `np.amin(A, axis=2)`.

---

### Old version

If you apply the solution from [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37328910/2692283) to **more than 2 dimensions**, the provided solution will not work in any case. After fighting with this problem for a long time, I found a solution which seems to work (I tested it for some cases). If you find any problem with this solution, I would be happy for any comment.

#### Problem

So first the problem (which is similar to the problem I had). Try for example:

```
In [1]: A = np.array([[[5, 1, 2, 3]], [[3, 5, 1, 7]]])
```

The second dimension is in this case just 1 (`A` has a shape of `(2,1,4)`). Then

```
In [2]: np.amin(A, axis=2)
```

will result in

```
Out[2]: array([[1],
               [1]])
```

which is as expected.

While on the other side, if you apply

```
In [3]: min_idx = np.argmin(A, axis=2)
In [4]: A[np.arange(A.shape[0]), np.arange(A.shape[1]), min_idx]
```

you get

```
Out[4]: array([[1, 5],
               [2, 1]])
```

which is not equal to the `amin` solution from `In [2]`.

#### Old Solution

What is possible, is to squeeze the `min_idx` (from `In [3]`) before you use it as index and to reshape it afterwards again:

```
In [5]: sq_idx = np.squeeze(min_idx)
In [6]: min_pre = A[np.arange(A.shape[0]), np.arange(A.shape[1]), sq_idx]
In [7]: np.reshape(min_pre, (2,1))
```

which finally results in:

```
Out[7]: array([[1],
               [1]])
```

---

I would suggest two more steps to optimize the solution a little bit.

**(1)**

In order to simplify the indexing of the array:

```
shp = [np.arange(i) for i in A.shape]
```

which simplifies `In [6]` with:

```
min_pre = A[shp[0], shp[1], sq_idx]
```

**(2)**

In order to generalize the reshape, `In [7]` can be replaced by

```
np.reshape(min_pre, tuple(np.asarray(A.shape)[:-1]))
```

---

I hope it helps someone :)

Comment: Instead of using np.arange, for higher rank arrays you want to use np.mgrid, e.g.- i,j=np.mgrid[0:2,0:1]; A[i, j, min_idx], which fixes your problem in a simpler way than your suggested solution.

Comment: In principle it's a great idea, but `mgrid` returns the arrays in columns. So it would be necessary to squeeze all of them before usage, like `A[np.squeeze(i), A.squeeze(j), min_idx]`. In that case I'd need to apply the for-loop anyhow. Do you have an idea how I could transform the `mgrid` such that I can apply it directly?

Comment: After I had problems with my own solution in higher dimensions, I searched for a better solution and found that `take_along_axis` is exactly doing what we need! I updated my answer.